# pushbots crash: Runtime exception

Tags: android

My app crashes when run on AVD.
1)Did all the prescribed things by pushbots.
2)The jar file addition.
3)The extended class but no use.
  my app crashes

THE ERROR LOG IS:

```
07-04 22:25:05.994: E/Trace(628): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)

07-04 22:25:06.152: D/AndroidRuntime(628): Shutting down VM

07-04 22:25:06.152: W/dalvikvm(628): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a13300)

07-04 22:25:06.172: E/AndroidRuntime(628): FATAL EXCEPTION: main

07-04 22:25:06.172: E/AndroidRuntime(628): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate application com.csconnect: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.csconnect

07-04 22:25:06.172: E/AndroidRuntime(628):  at android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplication(LoadedApk.java:501)

07-04 22:25:06.172: E/AndroidRuntime(628):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4124)

07-04 22:25:06.172: E/AndroidRuntime(628):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1300(ActivityThread.java:130)

07-04 22:25:06.172: E/AndroidRuntime(628):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1255)

07-04 22:25:06.172: E/AndroidRuntime(628):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)

07-04 22:25:06.172: E/AndroidRuntime(628):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)

07-04 22:25:06.172: E/AndroidRuntime(628):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)

07-04 22:25:06.172: E/AndroidRuntime(628):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)

07-04 22:25:06.172: E/AndroidRuntime(628):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)

07-04 22:25:06.172: E/AndroidRuntime(628):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)

07-04 22:25:06.172: E/AndroidRuntime(628):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)

07-04 22:25:06.172: E/AndroidRuntime(628):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

07-04 22:25:06.172: E/AndroidRuntime(628): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.csconnect

07-04 22:25:06.172: E/AndroidRuntime(628):  at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:61)

07-04 22:25:06.172: E/AndroidRuntime(628):  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501)

07-04 22:25:06.172: E/AndroidRuntime(628):  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)

07-04 22:25:06.172: E/AndroidRuntime(628):  at android.app.Instrumentation.newApplication(Instrumentation.java:967)

07-04 22:25:06.172: E/AndroidRuntime(628):  at android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplication(LoadedApk.java:496)

07-04 22:25:06.172: E/AndroidRuntime(628):  ... 11 more
```

THE MANIFEST FILE IS:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.csconnect"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="20" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<!-- GCM requires a Google account. -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.DISABLE_KEYGUARD"/>

<permission android:name="com.csconnect.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
android:protectionLevel="signature" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.csconnect.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />


<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
     android:name="com.csconnect"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.csconnect.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>

            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.csconnect.MESSAGE" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>




    <activity android:name="com.pushbots.push.PBMsg"/>
    <activity android:name="com.pushbots.push.PBListener"/>
    <receiver
                android:name="com.google.android.gcm.GCMBroadcastReceiver"
                android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
    <intent-filter>
    <!-- Receives the actual messages. -->
    <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
    <!-- Receives the registration id. -->
    <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />
    <category android:name="com.csconnect" />
    </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
    <receiver android:name="com.pushbots.push.MsgReceiver" />
    <service android:name="com.pushbots.push.GCMIntentService" />
    <service android:name="org.openudid.OpenUDID_service" >
    <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="org.openudid.GETUDID" />
    </intent-filter>
    </service>




    <activity
        android:name="com.csconnect.SecondActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_second" >
    </activity>
    <!-- GCM connects to Google Services. -->

   </application>


</manifest>
```

THE MAINACTIVITY FILE IS:

```
package com.csconnect;

import com.pushbots.push.Pushbots;

import android.app.Activity;






public class MainActivity extends Activity {


public  String PUSHBOTS_APPLICATION_ID = "---#the application ID#---";
public String SENDER_ID="-----#the sender ID-----#";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
     Pushbots.init(this, SENDER_ID,PUSHBOTS_APPLICATION_ID);



    Button inboxbutton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

    inboxbutton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this , SecondActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);

        }
    });






  }



}
```

Comment: i tried whatever is required but still its the same thing...i crated a new project just to test Pushbots and it is having the same problem.PLease help anyone...im short of deadline...by the way...when i did it in a new project as u said stacktry...the error log is again the same...dont know what to do:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**The Wrong Way:**
Right click main project, choose `Properties -> Java Build Path -> Projects -> Add...`, this add the Android library Project as a dependency project in Android main project's build path, this does not work. If all required Android-related resources are defined in main project, you will not get any error at compile time, but when run the application, you get the exception described in the question.

**The Correct Way:**
Right click main project, choose `Properties -> Android`, in the Library section, add your Android library project here. Check out official dev guide [Referencing a library project](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/projects/projects-eclipse.html#ReferencingLibraryProject). This should fix all your problem. Also note that you have to use relative path reference the actual Android library project, as stated in the [Library Project - Development considerations](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/projects/index.html#considerations).

Comment: i tried this but its not working ..please help in any other way

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem. I added the library in the correct way but had the same porblem. My solution was to update the android-support-v4.jar to android-support-v13.jar. Afterwards it worked perfect!!